# VBA Excel problem with creation the new sheet under custom name

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create the sheet under the specified name.

Unfortunately, I keep receiving an error, that object is required.

The code looks like this:

```
Sub GetJoins()
Dim tws As Worksheet, nws As Worksheet
Dim shnm As String
Set tws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Frontsheet")
shnm = tws.Range("B4").Value
Set nws = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Frontsheet")).Name = shnm
End Sub
```

Why does it keep asking about the object?

Comment: It has been a loooong time since I've used VBA, but I believe `set` must be used on an object, however, here set is assigned to ...Name = shnm, so to the string (if that is even allowed?)  You could just omit the `set nws=`, so only use ` Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Frontsheet")).Name = shnm`  Or do two lines, first `Set nws = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Frontsheet"))`  and then `nws.Name = shnm`. At least ,that's without testing and based on rusty VBA knowledge

Comment: You'd be correct in believing this and quite a fitting name to comment on this particular problem @Me.Name

Comment: @Notus_Panda Yeah, didn't want to use `this.name`  at the time :D

Answer (score 0):

this code worked for me.

```
Sub GetJoins()
    Dim tws As Worksheet, nws As Worksheet
    Dim shnm As String
    
    ' Set reference to the "Frontsheet" worksheet
    Set tws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Frontsheet")
    
    ' Get the sheet name from cell B4 in the "Frontsheet" worksheet
    shnm = tws.Range("B4").Value
    
    ' Add a new worksheet after "Frontsheet" and assign the desired name
    Set nws = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Frontsheet"))
    nws.Name = shnm
End Sub
```

You have just a minor mistake while you trying to assign the name.

Comment: Now I am getting an error: Method 'Name' of object'_Worksheet' failed